# Document manager in symfony2 in console command

Tags: symfony-2.1

I need a cron job for my symfony site. I have found tutorial to create console command in
http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/cookbook/console/console_command.html

My command.php

> namespace xxx\WebBundle\Command;
>
> use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command; use
>   Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument; use
>   Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface; use
>   Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption; use
>   Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
>
> class GreetCommand extends Command {
>       protected function configure()
>       {
>
> ```
> }
>
> protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
> {
>
>     $em = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager();
>     $em->getRepository('xxxWebBundle:Wishlist')->findAll();
>    // $output->writeln($text);
> }
> ```
>
> }

When I call command in console, getting error " Call to undefined method xxxx\WebBundle\Command\MyCommand::getContainer() "
How can I get the document manger in execute function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to extends `ContainerAwareCommand` to have access to `$this->getContainer()`

```
namespace xxx\WebBundle\Command;

//Don't forget the use
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

class GreetCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand { 
  protected function configure() {}

  protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
  {

    $em = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager();
    $em->getRepository('xxxWebBundle:Wishlist')->findAll();
    // $output->writeln($text);
  } 
}
```